# gridview row count not equal gridview DataSource row count

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, count, row

I have the following code:

```
        dgvServices.DataSource = SQL.DBDS.Tables[0];
        if (dgvServices.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //dgvServices.Rows[0].Selected = true;
            dgvServices.SelectRow(intSelectedRow);
            dgvServices.SelectedIndex = intSelectedRow;

        }
```

After setting the DataSource (dgvServices.DataSource = SQL.DBDS.Tables[0];), the row count of the DataSource is 21214.

However the row count in the next line (dgvServices.Rows.Count) is 0.
Therefore my if statement does not execute. Why?

Comment: Because data is not bound to the GridView. Therefore it has no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to bind the data.
So added the statement:

dgvServices.DataBind();

between the 2 other statements.